# How to login to bash with current user, and the user's .bashrc file, in jupyterlab?

Tags: bash, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have a configuration file setup in .bashrc which I would like to apply to all terminals opened automatically in my jupyterlab.

Currently jupyterlab terminals start like this, without any of the configuration in my .bashrc file.

[image: jupyterlab terminal]

If I simply type bash and hit enter it does exactly what I want. Like below.

[image: terminal after typing bash]

I would like for it to automatically open like this.

How can this be achieved?

[Here is a very similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467098/how-can-the-terminal-in-jupyter-automatically-run-bash-instead-of-sh)

But none of the solutions work, I mean it does open bash, not shell, so I'm not sure if that solution is what I'm looking for. But I've changed my tornado settings, I've added the environment variable SHELL=/bin/bash but none of it has any affect. (I've obviously restarted jupyterhub each time to see the effect.

Here is my jupyterhub start file 'jupyterhub.service', located in '/etc/systemd/'.

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyterhub
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
Environment="PATH=/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
Environment="SPARK_HOME=/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/"
Environment="SHELL=/bin/bash"
ExecStart=/anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyter/jupyterhub_config.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: The underlying platform probably also matters. On some GUIs a new terminal will be a "login" shell whereas on others it won't; and so what exactly the shell's startup files *should* do depends on that.

Comment: Depends on what? I'm unsure what you mean. I updated JupyterLab to the latest version to no avail.

Comment: If you are on Linux, your startup files do one thing. If you are on a Mac, they do something slightly different. On Windows, abandon all hope. Which of these are you on? (And obviously if you have *substantial* customizations in these files, mention that too.)

Comment: It's on Linux, Ubuntu, I updated the post with my jupyterhub start file.

Comment: It looks like you need to tell Jupyter that you want a login shell (`bash --login -i`) or else to `source ~/.bashrc`. Maybe try changing `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to include `c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['/bin/bash --login -i']}`

Comment: I'll give this a go thanks, can you confirm or deny that my jupyterhub_config.py fiie which I use when launching jupyterhub as seen above is the same or overrides the jupyter_notebook.config.py file, which I don't have?

Comment: Didn't work when I put it in jupyterhub_config.py anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a file

```
$HOME/.bash_login
```

and source `.bashrc` from there

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

and see if it does what you wanted.

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2011#issuecomment-422620768), bashrc needs to be sourced from profile.

I've confirmed this works by adding the following to `/home/jovyan/.profile`:

```
bash
source /home/jovyan/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me do some wild guess for what happened:

#### 1. Config issue

As one of the comment said, change `jupyter_notebook_config.py` to include

```
c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['/bin/bash', '--login', '-i']}
```

The `shell_command` should be an array of three strings. See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4042

#### 2. Your id or your shell

Check these right after you launch the terminal

```
$ whoami
$ echo $SHELL
```

to see you have the right user and right shell. If your user is not right, it is expecting the `.bashrc` in a different user's home directory. If your shell is not right, e.g., `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` (which in fact are often hard-link of each other), it will not read `.bashrc`

If so, try to see if your `$SHELL` env variable as seen by Jupyter is correct. Jupyter should use that if you didn't specify `shell_command` as above

#### 3. Jupyter may be giving you a non-interactive shell

If your bash really doesn't read your .bashrc, it may be invoked as non-interactive shell (I don't know how). To check you can try run this:

```
$ ls
$ !!
```

The first `ls` command can be any command. The second `!!` is to use bash's history expansion to recall the last executed command. If will not substitute if it is not an interactive shell.

I don't expect that and I don't know how to fix if this happens.

Comment: I only have a jupyterhub_config.py not a jupyter_notebook_config.py, will this work? Or do I need both?

Answer (score 1):

I have the very same problem when configuring **JupyterLab** (similar to **JupyterHub**) as a Systemd-Service.

###### First Solution

(*Please first try the second solution.*)
We can address the problem by change the default configuration in `jupyter_notebook_config.py` (as one of the comment and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60215686/6571140) said, but **the conclusion/solution is just the reverse**.)

> The related comment: [image]

The file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` is located at `$HOME/.jupyter/`. If it does not exist, it can be generated by running:

```sh
jupyter lab --generate-config
```

After this file is located, we modify the content as follows:

```py
# This is for Jupyter Notebook
# c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['/bin/bash']}
# This is for JupyterLab/JupyterHub
c.ServerApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['/bin/bash']}
```

Notably, the options `'--login', '-i'` mentioned in above comment and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60215686/6571140) prevent the terminal loading `.bashrc`.
Without these options, the shell looks like (which is expected):

```sh
(base) [ml@soc3 /]$ python --version
Python 3.9.5
```

While with these options, the shell looks like (not initilized with `.bashrc`):

```sh
bash-4.2$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

---

###### Second Solution

create or edit the `~/.bash_profile` file to automaitically load `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

After reading more about [login and interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187389/6571140), I found that the default behavior of Jupyter's terminal is login and interactive, and it will source the `~/.bash_profile` if the file exists (usually, it will load the `~/.bashrc` file). My problem is that I created a new user for running JupyterLab, while the default `~/.bash_profile` is not created for this user, and hence `~/.bashrc` will not be sourced. Furthermore, I have previously run JupyerLab with `root` user, which has the mentioned configuration files, thus the JupyerLab terminal works well.

> I think it is more sounded. Though the first solution works, why it works is not clear to me.